# Register click event for User Control in Page_Init method

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I'm having a bit of trouble with my dynamically added user controls.

The user controls are just a simple textbox, checkbox and button. They are being added to the page fine in the Page_Init method, but the button Click event isn't firing and I'm assuming I need to subscribe to this seperately.

Is this correct? If so, how do I do it?

My current Page_Init method is below. Thanks in advance!

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyList = new List<Control>();
        PropertyList = Session["propertyList"] as List<Control>;
        if (PropertyList != null)
        {
            foreach (AddProperty prop in PropertyList)
            {
                this.propPlaceholder.Controls.Add(prop);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks flawed from the start. The controls are not meant to be persisted in the session across calls. I'd suggest another design to not be bitten by nasty bugs later on.

Comment: Hi Anders, Thanks for that- this is only a temporary system so we are happy with it in this. Any ideas as to how I can subscribe to the event?

Comment: donpisci, where are the controls instantiated? On the Page_Init you are just adding them to a placeholder, but where are they actually created (new and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the click event with the controls